# Why uncaught exception: Error in Actionscript. when connected to Stackoverflow.com?

Tags: javascript, firefox, actionscript, cross-domain, stack-overflow

As I'm looking for answers on StackOverflow, I notice a console error that keeps looping in my Javascript log.

```
uncaught exception: Error in Actionscript. Use a try/catch block to find error.
```

Whenever I close the StackOverflow tab, it stops. After looking (elsewhere) what it could be, i found out it's a cross-domain issue with Firefox.

Why is it popping up in my console of the tab where i'm working and not just on the StackOverflow tab? Why is StackOverflow throwing those error?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I thought the problem was my website.

Comment: I find it odd that this is mentioning Actionscript in the console, which is used by Flash. It would seem to me that there is an error on some Flash-based element of the StackOverflow website. As to why it shows up across the board? Heaven only knows.

Comment: Try to read the following question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638641/how-do-i-fix-this-cross-domain-actionscript-3-error

Should help.