# recorder.js uncaught exception: Error in Actionscript. Use a try/catch block to find error

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, audio, audio-recording

I am using https://github.com/jwagener/recorder.js/
At home it works like a charm. But as I tested it at the university, it doesnt work. I dont know why. Am I missing a flash plugin? Or does it depend on crossdomain? But the example should work anywhere though http://recorderjs.ponyho.st/examples/example-1.html

I guess it isnt possible to catch the exception in javascript as well.

```
try{
   record();
}catch(e){
   alert(e.message);
}
```

Comment: Javascript can't catch exception from actionscript, what is the exception from flash?

Comment: I dont know how I could figure it out or even where I should place the try/catch in the actionscript. Havent used actionscript so far.

Comment: Try to read [this][1] question. Should help.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638641/how-do-i-fix-this-cross-domain-actionscript-3-error