# "Error calling method on NPObject!" with Flowplayer

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript

This is very similar to this question: [Cross Domain ExternalInterface "Error calling method on NPObject"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038668/cross-domain-externalinterface-error-calling-method-on-npobject)

except that I don't have access to the flash - I'm using a pre-compiled swf from Flowplayer's website. Is there any way of doing this without modifying the swf itself?

Comment: I was not able to figure this out. I had to move the player swf into the main domain unfortunately.