# Firefox "Bad NPObject" error with swf only when using Function.apply()

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, firefox, externalinterface

I am struggling with flash and firefox (latest, 35.0.1) and can't find any solution.
I want to call an ActionScript function with javascript, using ExternalInterface.
So I wrote this simple javascript function (*App* is just an object to wrap my functions):

```
App.swfCall = function(callbackName, params) {
    var callback = $('#swf object, #swf embed')[0][callbackName];
    if(typeof(callback) === "function") {
        callback.apply(null, params); // executed but throws NPObject error...
    }
}
```

And Firefox throws an error:

> Bad NPObject as private data!

The only help I found about this error is not relevant with my issue, as:

- Everything is ready at this moment; actually the action is first initiated by a user action on the swf itself
- There is no cross-domain issues (everything on the same domain)

Actually, if I do not use the *Function* javascript object (either with *call()* or *apply()*), everything works fine. So **this** is working:

```
App.swfCall = function(callbackName, data) {
    var swf = $('#swf object, #swf embed')[0];
    if(typeof(swf[callbackName]) === "function") {
        swf[callbackName](data);
    }
};
```

Anyway there are many problems with this:

- I can just pass a single argument to the function
- ...And I have to check if the parameter is the "data" parameter is not null
- I cannot pass null parameters beacause of that (not the biggest issue)

So all I need is to be able to pass parameters to the swf (0, one or more!)
And I'd really like to understand what is happening, too.

I said there is no cross-domain issues, actually it is an iframe within facebook. But obviously everything is inside it and on the same domain, so it shouldn't be a problem.. should it?

Thank you!

Comment: try to read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038668/cross-domain-externalinterface-error-calling-method-on-npobject

Comment: Thanks, but my problem shouldnt be related to cross-domain issue, since everything is on the same domain. Anyway I'll try to set allowscriptaccess to "always", though since it's set to "sameDomain" by default, which should be sufficient. So I am not sure this is going to solve anything..

Comment: allowscriptaccess should be true it doesn't related to crossdomain policy, read documentation

Comment: I explicitely set allowscriptaccess to "always"; and as expected I still have the error. In your link System.security.allowDomain is also mentioned, though once again the original issue is with two files on 2 domains. Maybe I am misunderstanding something, but I still have this "Bad NPObject" error. And strangely it works just by not using a Function object... I dont get why. Anyway, thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put you parameters as an array to your function you can try it with the new in ECMA6 defined Spread Operator:

```
App.swfCall = function(callbackName, data) {
  var swf = $('#swf object, #swf embed')[0];
  if(typeof(swf[callbackName]) === "function") {
    swf[callbackName](....data);
  }
};
```

A description of the operator can be found here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

Comment: How do you enable ES6?

Comment: There's no need to activate. Recent Browser support it! See https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/